# How to create create JSON object ( of form elements) of dynamic html form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, forms, dom

Trying to create dynamic HTML forms and save them, I can create dynamic forms using bootstrap but on submit i am struggling to create JSON of this dynamic form. 
I am looking to save something like this

```
{
 "form" :
    [

        {
            "name" : "username",
            "id" : "txt-username",
            "caption" : "Username",
            "type" : "text",
            "placeholder" : "E.g. user@example.com"
        },
        {
            "name" : "password",
            "caption" : "Password",
            "type" : "password"
        },
        {
            "type" : "submit",
            "value" : "Login"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am not sure how i can achieve this.

Comment: what exacltly you want to achieve? you want to send all your form propertis? or only inputs?

Comment: All form properties which i created dynamically (html form). I want to save that JSON object of that form properties (type, value(if any), name, id..).

Comment: for send only values you can use $("form").serializeArray();...but for attributes I dont know...I think attr() function may help you.

Comment: I was trying with DOM, but there should be some standard way.. Ahhh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it:

```
function getAttrs(DOMelement) {
    var obj = {};
    $.each(DOMelement.attributes, function () {
        if (this.specified) {
            obj[this.name] = this.value;
        }
    });
    return obj;
}

$("form").each(function () {
    var json = {
        "form": []
    };
    $(this).find("input").each(function () {
        json.form.push(getAttrs(this));
    });

    $(this).find("select").each(function () {
        var select = getAttrs(this);
        select["type"] = "select";
        var options = [];
        $(this).children().each(function () {
            options.push(getAttrs(this));
        });
        select["options"] = options;
        json.form.push(select);
    });

    console.log(json);
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/j1g5jog0/

Update: http://jsfiddle.net/j1g5jog0/5/

Comment: There is one issue, <select> and its <options> are not captured by this solution.

Comment: @user986508 Ok, how you do you want select stored then, something like this? `{"type": select, "options": [{...}, {...}, {...}]}`

Comment: yes something like this, {
    "form": [
        {
            "name": "username",
            "id": "txt-username",
            "caption": "Username",
            "type": "text",
            "placeholder": "E.g. user@example.com"
        },
        {
            "name": "password",
            "caption": "Password",
            "type": "password"
        },
        {
            "name": "country",
            "type": "select",
            "options": [
                {
                    "name": "Japan"
                },
                {"name": "Thailand"},{"name": "Spain"}]}]}

Comment: @caeth  Thank you for the examples you have provided.Can you please help me that how can we see the data in successfully created in json object?